# How is constitutional monarchy perceived in Commonwealth realms other than United Kingdom?

Tags: public-opinion, canada, australia, constitutional-monarchy, commonwealth

Especially in countries with huge population and economy like Canada and Australia, what's the opinion of people about constitutional monarchy? Are there any well known groups or indivuals who opposes to the form of the government?

Comment: As a Canadian, I see no point to the monarchy.  However, I can't get excited enough to move for change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, Monarchy of Canada is not a subject of active discussions outside of academic circles. Although there is an organization in Canada called "[Citizens for a Canadian Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizens_for_a_Canadian_Republic)", founded in 2002, which advocates the replacement of the Canadian monarchy. Wikipedia articles [Monarchy of Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarch_of_Canada#Debate) and [Debate on the monarchy in Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debate_on_the_monarchy_in_Canada) has some useful information about the topic.

In Australia, political parties Australian Labor Party, The Greens and The Democrats support becoming a republic. Again, Wikipedia article [Republicanism in Australia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republicanism_in_Australia) explains republicanist movements in detail.

Comment: In Australia's case: we're not a republic yet because we can't decide what sort of republic we want to be. Once all the non-monarchists are united in a single system, then we're likely to succeed in the required referendum. And, of course, there are times when it is not respectful to discuss dropping the monarchy, especially when we'd like to stay in the Commonwealth...

Comment: However, I should say, in answer to the question, we're not too bothered by the constitutional monarchy itself; it serves us rather well. It is just that we should have our own head of state. The problem is, in making this change, we have to determine how to choose, and what, if any, powers are codified. These are where there's issues and indecisiveness.